Pandas: change multiple level column name to one level
I have a dataframe with two-level column names as:
ID   Value
A    B
----------------
1   6
2   5
3   4
4   3
5   2
6   1

I want to change the column head with:
column_mapping = {
    ('ID', 'A') : 'ID:A',
    ('Value', 'B'): 'Value:B'
}

I tried rename:
df.rename(columns=column_mapping, inplace=True)

which does not work.
Any idea how?

Try:
df.columns = df.columns.map(":".join)
print(df)

Prints:
   ID:A  Value:B
0   1.0      6.0
1   2.0      5.0
2   3.0      4.0
3   4.0      3.0
4   5.0      2.0
5   6.0      1.0

